# Install C standard library man pages on macOS

Tags: macos, unix, manpage

I recently updated the 2020 M1 Macbook pro I use for school to macOS Ventura, 13.4.1. Since then, I haven't been able to access C standard library man pages from the terminal. Any idea how I can regain access to the man pages?

For example, typing 'man 2 exit' just returns 'no manual entry for exit'. I have downloaded homebrew and xcode, but just downloading these resources hasn't fixed the problem.

Edit: I meant 'man 3 exit'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pages you're looking for are distributed with Xcode. `man` finds them using `xcode-select --show-manpaths`, so try running that to see if everything is installed correctly. On my machine, the `exit(3)` page is in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man3/exit.3`.

How do I know that? Well, `man` is [open source](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/man/blob/d1a6cf297112328e7a7f1aa30abb632f03bc3af5/man/man.sh#L931-L942). You can go look at how it works. (And it's just a shell script.)

Also useful, you can pass `-d` (or `-dd`) to get information about where `man` is looking for things and where it find them.

My guess is that `xcode-select` isn't set up properly. It might point to some uninstalled version. In that case use `xcode-select -s` to set the correct version as default. If you use multiple versions of Xcode, I highly recommend [Xcodes.app](https://github.com/XcodesOrg/XcodesApp), which does a great job of maintaining that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, typing 'man 2 exit' just returns 'no manual entry for exit'.

The `exit` function (and the rest of the standard library) are in section 3, not 2. Typing

```
man 3 exit
```

will get you the documentation for the standard library's `exit` function.

Section 2 documents system calls. Try `man man` to get a list of the standard man page sections.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, however that command still yields "no manual entry for exit".